# Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 9000 when debugging dockerized flask app using pycharm

Tags: python, docker, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a flask app in Pycharm debugger that runs using Docker containers on my Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS.
I added the following piece of code for that purpose in my `extensions.py`.

```
pydevd_pycharm.settrace(
    "host.docker.internal",
    port=9000,
    stdoutToServer=True,
    stderrToServer=True,
    suspend=False,
)
```

However, I am getting the error: `Could not connect to host.docker.internal: 9000`. when I run `docker-compose -f  up -d --build --remove-orphans`. My `/etc/hosts` does not specifcy any mapping for `host.docker.internal` either which might have caused the issue.

I tried changing `host.docker.internal` to `localhost` but no luck. Below is my debug config for python debug server. Anyone help please!

[image]

Comment: Are you running under Linux, MacOS, or Windows?

Comment: I am running it on Ubuntu